# Should name suffix (Jr. Sr. III) be a separate field?

Tags: database-design

An existing data model defines a person's name as having the following attributes:

- first_name
- middle_name
- last_name

The last_name also include various suffixes such as Jr. Sr. III, etc.

One issue with this is that a query such as `where last_name = 'Brown'` will miss `Brown Jr.`  Is this a good enough reason to have the suffixes in a separate nullable field? What would be the downside of doing that?

Comment: A nice read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: His last name isn't `Brown Jr`, it's `Brown`. `Jr` is part of his first name, really. I would keep it as a separate column though, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One issue with this is that a query such as where last_name = 'Brown' will miss Brown Jr.

That's not really an issue. Just do `WHERE last_name LIKE '%Brown%'`. Generally, I don't put them in separate fields because my word loads don't require it. You can go by the name `Jo2e Bob44` and I don't much care. Sometimes I break things apart into First Name, and Last Name to build Rolodex functionality or custom sorts.

The only time I think the application requires it would be if you're making an ancestry.com or the like. I could see it being more significant there.

Comment: Doesn't LIKE affect performance quite a bit?  Honest question.  Another question: if someone goes to look them up by Brown and doesn't see the record, then they'll add a new record for the same person (one with Brown Jr. and the other with Brown).

Comment: Doesn't LIKE affect performance quite a bit? Yes, but it's still totally functional and works for most applications just use a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html).

Comment: Yes, you always have a potential for dupes you can't avoid it unless you collect unique numbers like (SSNs or DL) and even then sometimes they pop up. Google Contacts and other large installs solves this with "Find and Merge Duplicates" which provides you a list of things it thinks are dupes, that you can QA and merge.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I guess.  But then this query will not find `Brown`: `WHERE last_name LIKE '%Brown Jr.%'`

Comment: @ebhh2001 SOUNDEX (or similar functions) might help with that.

Comment: You may find my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190959/34007) helpful. You could separate out the name(s) from the suffix (and title come to that) and use only the actual name for searching but have a `VIRTUAL` display-name that shows the lot when you wish to use these.